# Preview.app: How can I quickly find all highlights with specific colour in PDF?

Tags: pdf, preview, skim

I have a couple of PDFs (some of which are 500+ pages long). In these PDFs I made a lot of highlights, when I read through them. I came up with a colouring system, such that each colour is associated with a particular theme. Now I would like to focus on one theme/colour. I.e. quickly jump through, say the Pink highlights. However Preview.app, in its 'Highlights & Notes' panel, only shows colour for notes. I am not able to see which colour I used on the highlights.

Can I somehow get an overview of the highlights and their highlight colour? Perhaps in a different program (Skim)?

[image]

Comment: To add a quick note; you cannot do this in preview.app. So you don't have to spend hours searching for it. The app is very minimal in functionality.

Comment: Not even if you wrote an AppleScript or use Automator, or something along those lines to export highlights?

Comment: @bonna You might be able to do some AppleScript magic to export highlights somehow, but I doubt you could do it by color.

Comment: Can you please add an answer as the current one's link does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this [link](http://www.organognosi.com/export-skim-notes-according-to-their-highlight-colors/) where someone used Skim and additional AppleScripts to do exactly what you are looking for, I think.

**Update:** As the above link is currently inactive, the page can also be reached on [blogspot](https://organognosi.blogspot.de/2011/06/export-skim-notes-according-to-their.html) and [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20170222192015/https://organognosi.blogspot.de/2011/06/export-skim-notes-according-to-their.html).

Comment: This link is broken can you please fix it or explain what the answers was.

Answer (score 0):

click on the dropdwon in the top left corner. find highlights nd notes

Comment: Yes, then I'll see _all_ my highlights and notes. But I would like to see only those highlight and notes that have _a specific color_, say green or blue. Is this possible?